# how to deploy a lightswitch application as aWebpart in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Does anyone know what the steps there are to deploy a **lightswitch** application as a Webpart in **Sharepoint 2010**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LightSwitch applications require .NET 4 framework, SharePoint 2010 is .NET 3.5 only ==> you cannot do it.